# If both nitric acid and nitrate ion are stabilised through resonance, what makes the nitrate ion more stable in aqueous medium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, stability, resonance

If both nitric acid and nitrate ion are stabilised through resonance, what makes the nitrate ion more stable in aqueous medium?

Can the same argument be applied to nitrous acid and nitrite ion in aqueous medium?

Comment: The nitrate ion is _very_ strongly solvated by the surrounding water molecules.  See this excellent answer that probably answers your question too: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32426/are-all-no3-salts-soluble-in-water-if-so-why